# Prove $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$ using delta epsilon definition

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Prove $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$ using delta epsilon definition.

So I did $|x-2|<\delta$ and $|1/x -1/2|<\varepsilon$.

The second inequality can be written as $|(2-x)/2x|<\varepsilon$ and this can be written as $|(x-2)/2x|<\varepsilon$  but now there is a $2x$ in the denominator.

Because I could write $|x-2|<\varepsilon 2x$ but then delta depends on x if I choose $\delta= \varepsilon 2x$. I could take a nearby point and say    $|x-2|<1$ so $1<x<3$ then delta would be $6\varepsilon$ this also doesnt seem right.

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This will be a lot easier to read if you [typeset your math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): e.g., `$|x-2| < \delta$` for $|x-2| < \delta$.

Comment: Four questions already asked...I think it's time to learn how to type mathematics here.

Comment: Im sorry for the typing. Yes N.F Taussig your equation is correct

Comment: $|x-2| < \ delta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that given any $\varepsilon>0$ that there exists a number $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|x-2|<\delta$, $\left|\frac1x-\frac12\right|<\varepsilon$.

Since we are interested in the behavior of $\frac1x$ when $x$ is "close" to $2$, let's limit the interval over which we examine such behavior.  So, let's agree to look in the interval $1<x<3$ or $|x-2|<1$.  While this is arbitrary, it is fit for purpose here.

Now that we've agreed to restrict $x$ to the interval $(1,3)$, we can write

$$\left|\frac1x-\frac12\right|=\frac{|x-2|}{|2x|}<\frac12 |x-2|\tag1$$

The right-hand side of $(1)$ is less than and given $\varepsilon>0$ when $|x-2|<2\varepsilon$.

Hence, if we take $\delta>0$ as the smaller of $1$ and $2\varepsilon$, then we can assert that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta=\min(1,2\varepsilon)$ such that

$$\left|\frac1x-\frac12\right|<\varepsilon$$

whenever $0<|x-2|<\delta$.

$$$$

Comment: Thanks, where does the 1/2 in front of |x-2| come from?

Comment: The factor $1/2$ is due to the estimate for $2x$.  Since we agreed to limit the interval for $x$ as $x\in (1,3)$, then $2<2x$ and hence $\frac1{2x}<\frac12$.

Comment: I agree on the interval of x as {1,3} so you estimate then that    1<x<3 and multiplaying by two would give    2 <2x< 6  . why dont we take the six, for example, then delta would be six times epsilon?

Comment: Well, note that any smaller $\delta$ works too.  But we cannot  (necessarily) use $6$ since $\frac1{2x}$ is greater than $\frac16$, not less than $\frac16$

Comment: yes I see it now. Thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Another question, I I have lim x-2 f(x)=2 show with the delta epsilon definition that there exists a delta>0 such that f(x)>1 if [x]<delta. How to solve this?

Comment: Hi Robin.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  Could you rewrite using Mathjax so that I can read the statement?

Comment: I dont know how to write math, do i need to install a program or plugin?

Comment: Oh.  How did you write your posted question?

Comment: But if the limit is $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=2$, then for $\epsilon=1$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|x-2|<\delta$, $$1<f(x)<3$$since for $\epsilon=1$, $2+\epsilon=3$ and $2-\epsilon=1$.

Answer (score 2):

$|x-2|< \delta \Leftrightarrow 2-\delta<x<2+\delta$ so if $\delta<1$ then $|x|=x>1$.

Now $|(2-x)/2x|=\frac{|2-x|}{2x}<\frac{|2-x|}{2}<\varepsilon$ can you finish from here?

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is a number such that $|x-2| < 1$, then $x>1$, and so $$\frac1{2x} < \frac12.$$ Hence, for any $x$ such that $0 < |x-2| < \min\{1,2\varepsilon\}$ we have that
$$\bigg|\frac{x-2}{2x}\bigg| = \frac{1}{2x} \cdot |x-2| < \frac12 \cdot 2\varepsilon = \varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming wlog $|x-2|<1 \iff 1<x<3$ we have

$$\left|\frac{x-2}{2x}\right|<\frac{\left|x-2\right|}{2}<\varepsilon \iff|x-2|<2\varepsilon $$

then we can take $\delta =\min(1;2\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Why does 2x in denominator becomes just 2?

Comment: @RobinBarels Since $2x> 2$ then $\left|\frac{x-2}{2x}\right|<\frac{\left|x-2\right|}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking for the limit when $ x $ goes to $ 2 $, You can assume that $ x $ is not far from $ 2 $. In other words, you can assume that $ x $ satisfies the condition :
$$1<x<3\;\; \text{ or }\;\; |x-2|<\color{red}{1}$$

So $$|\frac{x-2}{2x}|<\frac 12|x-2|$$

thus, to satisfy the condition $$|\frac 1x-\frac 12|<\epsilon$$

we just need
$$\frac 12|x-2|<\epsilon$$
or
$$|x-2|<2\epsilon$$.

Finally, we look for $ \delta>0$ such that

$$|x-2|<\color{red}{1} \; and\; |x-2|<\delta \implies |x-2|<2\epsilon$$
Thus, we will choose
$$\delta=\min(\color{red}{1},2\epsilon)$$

Comment: @MarkViola Sincerly, i did not see or read your answer.

Comment: I know.  There would not have been enough time to do so.   And this has happened to me before.  So, no worry. ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks, i appreciate with respect.

Comment: Of course.  There are some users on this site that aren't, for lack of a better word, nice.

Comment: Where did the 1/2 in front of |x-2| come from?

Comment: @RobinBarels It come from the fact that $$\frac 12\frac 1x <\frac 12 because $\frac 1x<1$.